# Uncaught TypeError:Undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I get the message `Uncaught TypeError:Undefined is not a function` when I try to call a the method in my home controller.

Advice perhaps as to why I am getting this message?

```
findIdpActivities = function (pernr, callback) {
    restEndPoint = serviceBase + 'Home/FindIdpActivities';
    data = "{'perNr':'" + pernr + "'}";
    makeJsonDataAjaxCall(callback);
};

makeJsonDataAjaxCall = function (callback, obj) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: restEndPoint,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
};
```

executing the method upon button click.

```
$(document).on("click", "input[name=btnViewActivities]", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).parent().find("input[name=hiddenPerNr]").val();
    dataService.findIdpActivities(value);
});
```

and this is the method in the HomeController

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult FindIdpActivities(string perNr)
    {
        viewModel.GetIdpActivities(perNr);

        return Json(new
            {
                Activities = viewModel.IdpActivities
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a common javascript error that happens when you try to call a function before it is defined.

For instance, while this code works as expected:

```
var sayHello= function () {
    return 'Hello!'
};

alert(sayHello());
```

If you reverse the order of the statements the *"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"* error will occur:

```
alert(sayHello());

var sayHello= function () {
    return 'Hello!'
};
```

Hence, I suggest you double check that your scripts are being loaded correctly, and that the **findIdpActivities** is being properly initialized as a function of the **dataService** object.