# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph

I'm trying to save the output of a Google Graph as an image and keep getting the error of:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null

Here is the javascript:

```
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Callback that creates and populates a data table,
// instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
// draws it.
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Impressions', 'Clicks']
    <?
                while ($arrDate = mysql_fetch_assoc($resStats)) {
                    $arrDates[] = $arrDate;
                    echo ",['".$arrDate["fdate"]."', ".($arrDate["imps"] ? $arrDate["imps"] : 0).", ".($arrDate["clicks"] ? $arrDate["clicks"] : 0)."]";
                }
    ?>
]);

var options = {
    series: {
        0: {targetAxisIndex: 0},
        1: {targetAxisIndex: 1}
    },
    vAxes:{
        0: {title: 'Impressions', minValue: 0},
        1: {title: 'Clicks', minValue: 0}
    }
};

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartContainer'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}

function getImgData(chartContainer) {
var chartArea = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode;
var svg = chartArea.innerHTML;
var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('width', chartArea.offsetWidth);
canvas.setAttribute('height', chartArea.offsetHeight);


canvas.setAttribute(
    'style',
    'position: absolute; ' +
        'top: ' + (-chartArea.offsetHeight * 2) + 'px;' +
        'left: ' + (-chartArea.offsetWidth * 2) + 'px;');
doc.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvg(canvas, svg);
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
return imgData;
}

function saveAsImg(chartContainer) {
var imgData = getImgData(chartContainer);

// Replacing the mime-type will force the browser to trigger a download
// rather than displaying the image in the browser window.
    window.location = imgData.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
}

function toImg(chartContainer, imgContainer) {
var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
var img = doc.createElement('img');
img.src = getImgData(chartContainer);

while (imgContainer.firstChild) {
    imgContainer.removeChild(imgContainer.firstChild);
}
imgContainer.appendChild(img);
}
```

The bit of PHP that's in there outputs like this:

```
['Date', 'Impressions', 'Clicks'],
['Aug 24, 2012', 2, 0],['Aug 27, 2012', 3, 0],['Aug 28, 2012', 37, 0],['Aug 29, 2012', 17, 0]
```

And here is the button and div needed:

```
<button onclick="toImg(document.getElementById('chartContainer'), document.getElementById('img_div'));">Convert to image</button>
<div id="line_div"></div>
```

THIS: http://jsfiddle.net/SCjm8/157/ is a tutorial that I am trying to follow but have gotten stuck. Can someone please tell me how to make it so that When I click the button in my code it generated the image and places it in the Div?

Many Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help you: [Uncaught TypeError:Undefined is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492604/uncaught-typeerrorundefined-is-not-a-function)

Comment: I would love to help but your first step should be finding out where in the script you get the error. You can do this with the JavaScript console in your browser or with try catch blocks. Without knowing where in your code it's happening this is a really hard question to answer. It could be almost anything.